# Facebook javascript group feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
        function info(){
        FB.api("/169016859823150",'GET',{fields:name},function(response){
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=response.name;
        });
    }
```

So I have the code above working which returns the name of the group. I wanted to change it to get the Id and link of every post in a groups feed. I tried the code below and a bunch of variations but I'm missing something.

```
        function info(){
        FB.api("/169016859823150/feed",'GET',{fields:Id,link},function(response){
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=response.Id,link;
        });
    }
```

I have this from Graph API which gives me what I want. Just cant seem to get it into JS...

```
169016859823150?fields=feed{link,id}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You were not making correct js request.

```
function info(){
    FB.api("/169016859823150/feed",'GET',{fields: 'feed{link,id}'},function(response){
        // response.feed.data
    });
}
```